# How do I find the expected value of the hypergeometic distribution by direct integration?

Tags: probability, integration

I am curious on how to find the expected value of the hypergeometic distribution by direct integration.

I know that $\Gamma \left( x \right) = \int\limits_0^\infty {s^{x - 1} e^{ - s} ds}$, is this in any way related to the solution of the expected value of $E(x)$?

Another subquestion arises: What is the integral of $x!$, and for what boundaries are these defined? I know that there may be no closed form solution to this integral with today's list of special functions.

I googled and checked numerous references on integrals including the CRC Handbook of Integrals, to no avail.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Eo8FdPWlQm1i4ixfFt56sN-V6-OqE97K/view?usp=sharing) is my attempt at the question I asked.

I know there is a way to find it by direct integration and not using other means, will a series representation approach work?

Comment: This is the continuous version of the expectation for continuous distributions, what you want is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kP(X=k)$

Comment: The Hypergeometric distribution is discrete so it's expected value is not given by an integral but instead a summation.

Comment: But could we approximate it using the integrals,i know this doesnt follow the definition of expected values of discrete random variables but lets evaluate this inetgral for fun,how would you do it??

Comment: haha ok, well what I would suggest is to use the gamma function definition of the factorial (you get factorials by simplifying the choose function), then that would be an integral and you would use fubinis theorem to swap the integrals

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Except I think you're going to get gamma functions in the denominator, those are harder to swap.

Comment: ah,i see but how would I find the integral of $\int x! dx$

Comment: yeah exactly theres multiple gamma functions. You could try IBP on it

Comment: IBP?,wolfram could not evalute it

Comment: I think integration by parts will not work,the best i got was the beta function,a quotient of beta and gamma functions